# Install Mac OSX on a partition of a Windows notebook?

Tags: windows, macos, mac, partitioning

Can this be done? Don't care about legal issues just would like to know if possible. I have a 150GB partition on a HP DV6000 Vista machine and was tempted to try...

**Note** SuperUser does not condone nor advocate violating any terms of service or license agreements.

Comment: Not programming related and also violates the EULA of Mac OS X.

Comment: @cletus: he specifically said he doesn't care about the EULA. Besides, the restrictions in Apple's EULA are immoral and should be illegal.

Comment: Immoral? You might need to consult a dictionary. You might not *like* them, but there's nothing immoral about Apple's restrictions.

Answer (score 5):

It is possibly and I found it not to be too tricky, even with a triple boot solution (Windows XP Home, kubuntu and OSX Tiger on a Dell Inspiron 8200).

If I remember correctly it only works if your notebook has an Intel processor with at least SSE2.

The [osx86project](http://wiki.osx86project.org/) is the right place to look for 
guidance. You have to look for installation images elsewhere however.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's a bit tricky but not impossible. Google "OSX x86".

Answer (score 0):

Don't believe you can because of the chip-set

The best alternative would be google "hackintosh".

Answer (score 0):

Specifically, take a look at http://wiki.osx86project.org/wiki/index.php/Installation_Guides#10.5.5_Guides .  Doable, but as lenni said, very non-trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is virtualisation - you can run OS X in VMware workstation, however it is rather slow (on my old Pentium D machine at least). It's fully functional - the only real issue is that it does not support widescreen resolutions. The legality of this of course is probably questionable.

Comment: It does. I've run it at 1366x768, 1920x1200 and 1280x1024 resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is](http://mytenpennies.wikidot.com/blog:installing-mac-osx-leopard-on-hp-laptop) how I did it on *my* HP dv6000 laptop.